# Limit convergence problem - Check if it is correct

Tags: general-topology

If I consider $\mathbb R$ with the Discrete Topology, with Cofinite Topology, and with the Semi-continuity Topology (the open are the half lines $[a, \infty)$ with $ a \in \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty\}$) and the sequence $x_n= \frac{1}{n}$. It is correct to say that

1. With the discrete topology it does not converge and there are no limits. Indeed $\{0\}$ is a neighborhood of itself that does not contain the other elements of $x_n$
2. With Cofinite Topology it does not converge and there are no limits. Indeed I can consider $\mathbb R - \{\frac{1}{2}\}$ as a neighborhood of $\{0\}$ that does not contains $\frac{1}{2}$.
3. With the Semi-continuity Topology it converges and the limit is $\{0\}$. Ideed every neighborhhod of $x$ contains every $x_n$ when $n$ is large enough.

Comment: Your arguments in (1) and (3) look great! I'd rethink (2) though: having a neighborhood of $0$ that doesn't contain a single point of a sequence isn't enough to make that sequence not converge to $0$ (think about the same sequence and the same neighborhood in the usual topology on $\Bbb R$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to 1. The argument needs to be sharpened: if $x \in \Bbb R$ then $\{x\}$ is open and contains at most 1 term of the sequence (as all terms of the sequence are different), and so $x_n$ does not converge to $x$, for *any* $x$. A priori, $0$ is not the only candidate, don't let the intuition of the standard topology mislead you..

No to 2: **any** $x$ in $\Bbb R$ is a limit of $(x_n)$: any open neighbourhood of $x$ misses at most finitely many terms of the sequence because all terms are different and the open neighbourhood has finite complement. $\Bbb R - \{\frac12\}$ contains all terms of the sequence for $n \ge 3$ so we do not disprove convergence this way (recall the definition: every neighbourhood of the limit must contain *almost all* (all but finitely many) terms of the sequence, not *all*!)

In 3: In fact it converges to any $x \le 0$, not just to $0$. Any neighbourhood of some $x \le 0$ contains $[x, +\infty) \supseteq \{x: x >0\} \supseteq \{x_n\mid n \in \Bbb N\}$, so here we do have all terms in every neighbourhood of $x$, so certainly all but finitely many.

So apply the *correct* definition of convergence and don't discard candidates too soon.